# How to require authentication for all pages with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have started to use Devise gem and now trying to implement the code, so my web app will require to login for each and every page on my app. I have added the following code to **routes.rb** according to [this instruction](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-authentication-for-all-pages):

```
authenticated :user do
  root to: 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
end
root to: redirect('/users/sign_in')
```

but it doesn't work. When I go to any page - it just open that page, and doesn't forward me to the sign_in page. Could anyone please clarify what I missed? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to your app controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

Comment: In case you need some pages public you can add only: [] and except: [] after the before_action

Comment: thank you - i will do this but i want the sign_in page to be public - what exactly do i have to put into the [ ] to enable the sign_in page to be public?

Comment: Correct. And if you have any child controllers that inherit from `ApplicationController` and need to have actions that skip/bypass that authentication (i.e. they're public pages), you can just add this to the top of their controllers: `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]`

Answer (score 0):

That's not enough. You still need to tell your controllers to require authentication for any action. In your case, the quickest way would be to add `before_action :authenticate_user!` to `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to combine authentication in the `routes.rb` and `before_action`, only in the `routes.rb` should be enough.

But if you want to redirect to the login, you should use `authenticate` instead of `authenticated`.

> With "authenticate", it is possible to make resources and routes that will ask for authentication before they can be accessed
>
> Replacing "authenticate" with "authenticated" in the above code causes the resource to simply be unavailable if the user is not authenticated
>
> https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-resource-actions-that-require-authentication-using-routes.rb

It should look like this:

```rb
authenticate :user do
  root to: 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
end
root to: redirect('/users/sign_in')
```